# SharedPreferences or Database?

Tags: android, database, sharedpreferences

I have two activity in my app say A & B. Activity A needs the data Stored by B (currently  Shared Preferences). But to query the data in Activity A i need the context of B. But, Activity A does not have any way to get the context of Activity B(according to the application flow). Is there any way around or using database will be a better option??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are storing in SharedPreferences then you do not need Activity B's context. Activity A's context can access the app's SharedPreferences as they are 'global' to the app.

Code Example

```
ActivityA.this.getSharedPreferences("SOMETHING", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

As to define if you need a database, you did not say what the data was you are storing. Therefore it is impossible to tell.

Answer (score 4):

Why do you need Activity A's context? You could just use `getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences()` within each activity to store/retrieve SharedPreferences.

Also, depending on what data you're storing, you may want to look into using an Intent to pass data from Activity A to Activity B. For example, to start Activity B from A you would use something like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityB.class);
i.putExtra("someIntData",1234);
i.putExtra("someStringData","yourdata");
startActivity(i);
```

And then wherever you need the data in ActivityB you could do:

```
int yourIntData = getIntent().getIntExtra("someIntData",0);
String yourStringData = getIntent().getStringExtra("someStringData");
```

This would be a faster because you don't have to hit the filesystem with SharedPreferences or a database.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
```

with either activity and it will return a `SharedPreferences` object tied to your app's package name, regardless of which activity you pass as a context.

Alternatively, you can pick a name for your shared preferences and pass it to the activity's `getSharedPreferences` method (as Sam_D and Graham point out in their answers).

Answer (score 1):

You can store all your data in SharedPreferences and you have access on them from every activity in your application.

Just do it like its explained here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref